# Adding newlines in Thunderbird config editor?

Tags: macos, thunderbird, about-config

How can I add newlines to values in Thunderbird's config editor? I ask because in the latest update, with `reply_on_top` set to `1`, there is no additional line break added before the quoted message, and I'd like to add it back in by editing `reply_header_ondate`.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a **\n** at the beginning of the string. it should work.

Comment: It does not work

Comment: how about <br />?

Comment: Nope! Still doesn't work. :-(

Comment: Maybe you should give SmartTemplate addon a try:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/smarttemplate/